# Upgrading AWS RDS Instance Class changes settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Does upgrading an AWS RDS instance (MySQL in my case) change settings when the database is rebooted, such as the Endpoint, Security Group settings and so on? Or does the values remain the same?

Basically, can I change the Instance Class without any worries about the current configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values remain the same. You just want to make sure you're prepared for the scheduled downtime. For a multi AZ deployment, it can be as little as five minutes of down time or less. For a non multi AZ deployment, it can take up to 30 minutes to modify the instance however it's not likely to take that long.